# AngularFire2 iterate through array of objects and get data from realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have to go through an array of items and fetch the prices in the realtime database, but I want to show a loading message on start and after I finish loading I want to remove the loading message, but the way I did the message does not work its removed before the end of loading:

```
let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: 'Waiting...'
});
loading.present();

for (let i = 0; i <= this.Cart.length - 1; i++) {
  let product = this.db.object('/menuItems/' + this.Cart[i].item.itemId);
  product.valueChanges().subscribe((prodData: any) => {
      if (prodData != null) {
          this.Cart[i].item.price = prodData.price[0]; 
      }
  });
}
loading.dismiss();
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: just curious, why are you not using Firestore? ...isn't using JavaScript's `Promise.all` to fetch those prices in parallel best practise, i.e., push each db read into an array then `Promise.all` that array. When the promise resolves, hide the indeterminate loader.

Comment: Hi, Ron, I am new with Firebase and I'm not quite sure how to do it, you can show an example of how to do it using Promise.all? Thanks.

Comment: it's actually no that hard: something like `var myArray = []` then for each read do `myArray.push(firebase.firestore().collection("prices").doc(itemId).get())`. Then after that iteration, after you fill the array, do `Promise.all(myArray).then`. The return values will be sitting at the index. (remember if a single read fails, the whole Promise.all fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the loading indicator inside the subscriber. The simplest way is to hide it when the first data comes in:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= this.Cart.length - 1; i++) {
  let product = this.db.object('/menuItems/' + this.Cart[i].item.itemId);
  product.valueChanges().subscribe((prodData: any) => {
      if (prodData != null) {
          this.Cart[i].item.price = prodData.price[0]; 
      }
      loading.dismiss();
  });
}
```

A bit more tricky is to hide it after all data comes back, but it doesn't have to be too hard. A simple way is to count how many responses you've gotten back. Once that is the same as the number of items in the cart, you can hide the loading indicator.

```
var responseCount = 0;
for (let i = 0; i <= this.Cart.length - 1; i++) {
  let product = this.db.object('/menuItems/' + this.Cart[i].item.itemId);
  product.valueChanges().subscribe((prodData: any) => {
      if (prodData != null) {
          this.Cart[i].item.price = prodData.price[0]; 
      }
      if (responseCount++ == this.Cart.length) loading.dismiss();
  });
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, I tried but I do not have enough reputation to vote.